# error NG8001 ; error TS2306; error NG1010 angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im a beginner to angular (im watching my first tutorial/course) and i ran in to this problem:

src/app/app.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'courses' is not a known element:

1. If 'courses' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Also this problem:

src/app/app.module.ts:6:34 - error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/user/hello-world/src/app/courses.component.ts' is not a module.

And This Problem:

src/app/app.module.ts:9:17 - error NG1010: Value at position 1 in the NgModule.declarations of AppModule is not a reference
Value could not be determined statically.

This is my courses.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: 'courses',
template: '\<h2\>Courses\</h2\>'
})
export class CoursesComponent {
}
```

This is my app.component.html

```
<h1>Angular</h1>
<courses></courses>
```

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `<` and `>` symbols in your template string, that can just be `'<h2>Courses</h2>'`.  Even better, use backticks `\`` instead of quotes and now you can have multiline template strings. This may not be the source of your problem, but what you have currently will output invalid HTML or at least some kind of error.

Comment: So I copied your code into a StackBlitz and it runs with no issues at all. Please take a look at this and see if you can make any changes that can reproduce your issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/finitelooper-ng16-wbd31g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcourses%2Fcourses.component.ts

Comment: It was the <h2></h2> that where messing my code, thank you so much!!